# custom conditional formats in excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

my goal is to format an entered text if a certain condition is met
e.g.

user enters "5" in a cell

format detects that it is greater than 3, appends "/a" [result: "5/a"]

user enters "2" in cell

format detects that is is less than 3, appends "/b" [result: "2/b"]

I tried [@"/a"][>3];[@"/b"][<3] but to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the built-in Conditional Formatting feature of Excel. You'll just need to apply two separate rules to the input cell.

Select the input cell and go to `Conditional Formatting > New Rule... > Use a formula to determine which cells to format`. If your input cell is A1, enter the formula

```
=A1>3
```

And set the format to the custom number format `#"\a"`.

Then do the same for the below rule, but with the formula

```
=A1<3
```

And the number format `#"\b"`.

If applying the rule to an entire range, refer to the top-left cell in the range in the conditional formatting formulas. For example, to apply the rule to `A1:C5`, the rules formulas would still be

```
=A1>3
```

Comment: how do I apply the rule conditions to multiple cells (without doing this each time)? I tried this and  format is based on the value of only a single cell in this case:a1.

Comment: @troubled I just edited my answer. The fixed references (the "$") were keeping it from working for an entire range. It should work now with only the two rules.

Comment: I've also found out how to do this be setting `Format Cells > Number > Custom > Text` to `[>3]#"/a";[<3]#"/b"`. Anyway, thankyou vmuch Excellll